# Uploading ID to same Azure Blob Index that a file is being uploaded to using .Net SDK

Tags: azure, azure-search-.net-sdk

I am uploading documents to my an Azure Blob Storage, which works perfect, but I want to be able to link and ID to this specifically uploaded document.

Below is my code for uploading the file:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file)
        {
            try
            {
                var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/Uploads"), file.FileName);
                string searchServiceName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SearchServiceName"];
                string blobStorageKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobStorageKey"];
                string blobStorageName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobStorageName"];
                string blobStorageURL = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BlobStorageURL"];

                file.SaveAs(path);

                var credentials = new StorageCredentials(searchServiceName, blobStorageKey);

                var client = new CloudBlobClient(new Uri(blobStorageURL), credentials);

                // Retrieve a reference to a container. (You need to create one using the mangement portal, or call container.CreateIfNotExists())
                var container = client.GetContainerReference(blobStorageName);

                // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myfile.gif".
                var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(file.FileName);

                // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
                using (var fileStream = System.IO.File.OpenRead(path))
                {

                    blockBlob.UploadFromStream(fileStream);
                }

                System.IO.File.Delete(path);

                return new JsonResult
                {
                    JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet,
                    Data = "Success"
                };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                throw;
            }

        }
```

I have added the ClientID field to the Index(It is at the bottom), but have no idea how I am able to add this to this index. This is still al nerw to me and just need a little guidance if someone can help :

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: How do you get the screen shot?

Comment: This is from the Azure Portal.

Comment: Can any one help me please ?